# Error: @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.11): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

Error firestore in react native Expo...

> ERROR  [2022-10-07T15:34:49.615Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.11): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Permission denied on resource project projectId: ,.
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
import "firebase/compat/storage";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);

export { firebase };
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.3",
    "expo": "~46.0.7",
    "expo-image-picker": "^13.3.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.6",
    "firebase": "^9.6.11",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.3",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7"
  },
```

Comment: Avoid using both the compat and modular SDKs. Have you tried using the [modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, you do not have permission to access the project you are trying to connect to.

```
Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Permission denied on resource project projectId: "jeries-database"
```

Check your firebase config once.